# How can I determine if the query is working?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I can't see if there's an error because the application is not prompting anything. I want to get a value from the database and put it inside a variable to be displayed later when I need it.

I'm fairly new to programming, I've tried to watch tutorials, but I just can't seem to get how some things are properly done since tutors have their own approach on doing stuff.

```java
public void selectQuery(String input) throws SQLException {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

        String USERNAME = "root";
        String PASSWORD = "root";
        String CONN_STRING =
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javaddy?serverTimezone=UTC";
        Connection connection =
            DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STRING, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

        try {
            String q = "SELECT Inquiry_answer,Inquiry_question FROM inquiries WHERE Inquiry_question = '" + input + "'";
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(q);
            String answer;
            answer = res.getString("Inquiry_answer");
            // /* there is no value returned here (I think) because after passing to
            // bot method, it doesn't print anything */
            bot(answer);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not find the database driver " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not connect to the database " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I expect to receive a value from the database but there is none returned.

Comment: In the try-catch enclosing the query string, the catch block should print the error message, so if you get an exception, then it can be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this is a pretty clear-cut case of when you should be using a debugger. I don't know what programming environment you are using, but all of the big ones (IntelliJ, Eclipse, Netbeans) have support for debugging built in. In this case, you should just set a breakpoint on the `bot(answer);` line, that way, you can determine whether there is any data there, check if the bot function is working correctly etc.

Also, as pointed above, if you're not getting a stacktrace, then the code is returning a value correctly. Maybe the relevant fields in the database are empty? Again, using a debugger can help you here.

Here's a sample tutorial for debugging Java programs in Eclipse in case you need one: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Without doing resultset.next() you can not get result.

Correct way of doing it:

```
                ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(q);
                String answer;
                res.next();
                answer = res.getString("Inquiry_answer");
                // /* there is no value returned here (I think) because after passing to
                // bot method, it doesn't print anything */
                bot(answer);
```

or still better way to put this code in loop like:

```
while (res.next())
{
  String answer = res.getString("Inquiry_answer");
  System.out.println(answer);
}
```

I suppose bot method prints string.